# Displaying error message next to input box using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, perl, validation

I have a really simple question, I am currently just editing my code below so that the error message for First Name appears next to the input box. This currently works however the error message appears underneath the input box and not next to it. Any advice on how to get the error message to appear next to the box would be greatly appreciated.

JavaScript file:

```
function checkFName() {

var Fname = document.forms["MyForm"]["Fname"].value;
if (Fname == null || Fname == "") {
    return true; 
}
}



function checkSName() {
var Sname = document.forms["MyForm"]["Sname"].value;
if (Sname == null || Sname == "") {
    return true;
}
}

function checkFLA() {
var FLA = document.forms["MyForm"]["Fline"].value;
if (FLA == null || FLA == "") {
    return true;
}
}

function checkSLA() {
var SLA = document.forms["MyForm"]["Sline"].value;
if (SLA == null || SLA == "") {
    return true;
}
}

function checkTown() {
var Town = document.forms["MyForm"]["Town"].value;
if (Town == null || Town == "") {
    return true;
}
}

function checkPcode() {
var Pcode = document.forms["MyForm"]["Pcode"].value;
if (Pcode == null || Pcode == "") {
    return true;
}
}

function checkEmail() {
var Email = document.forms["MyForm"]["Email"].value;
 atpos = Email.indexOf("@");
 dotpos = Email.lastIndexOf(".");
 if (atpos < 1 || ( dotpos - atpos < 2 ))   {
 return true;
 }    
 }



function f1() {
var bool = true;
if (checkFName(Fname)) {
var output = "First name must be entered";
document.getElementById("f4").innerHTML = output;
    bool = false;
}


if (checkSName(Sname)) {
    alert("Surname must be filled out");
    document.MyForm.Sname.focus();
    document.getElementById("Sname").style.border = '2px solid red';
bool = false;
}

    if (checkFLA(Fline)) {
    alert("First line of address must be filled out");
    document.MyForm.Fline.focus();
    document.getElementById("Fline").style.border = '2px solid red';
bool = false;
}

        if (checkSLA(Sline)) {
    alert("Second line of address must be filled out");
    document.MyForm.Sline.focus();
    document.getElementById("Sline").style.border = '2px solid red';
bool = false;
}


if (checkTown(Town)) {
    alert("Town must be filled out");
    document.MyForm.Town.focus();
    document.getElementById("Town").style.border = '2px solid red';
    bool = false;
}

if (checkPcode(Pcode)) {
    alert("Postcode must be filled out");
    document.MyForm.Pcode.focus();
    document.getElementById("Pcode").style.border = '2px solid red';
bool = false;
}

    if (checkEmail(Email)) {
    alert("This is not a valid email");
    document.MyForm.Email.focus();
    document.getElementById("Email").style.border = '2px solid red';
bool = false;
}
return bool;
}
```

Perl File:

```
   #!/xampp/perl/bin/perl  -w

require "dbfunc.pl";
use CGI qw/:standard/;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

print header;
print start_html("Customer Registration");

print_html_head_section();

print "<h1>Your Details</h1>\n";
print "Please Fill In Your Details Below<p>"; 

print qq!<form method="GET" name="MyForm" onsubmit="return f1()"    action="RegisterCustomerInsert.pl"><br />!;

print qq! Title: <select name="Title">  

<option value="Mr">Mr</option>
<option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
<option value="Miss">Miss</option>
<option value="Dr">Dr</option>
</select><br>!;



print qq! Firstname: <input type="text", name="Fname" , id="Fname" size=15>    <p id="f4"></p>! ;
print qq! Surname: &nbsp <input type="text", name="Sname" , id="Sname" size=15><br>! ;
print qq! First Line Of Address: <input type="text", name="Fline" , id="Fline" size=30> <br>! ;
print qq! Second Line Of Address: <input type="text", name="Sline" , id="Sline" size=30> <br>! ;
print qq! City / Town: <input type="text", name="Town" , id="Town" size=30> <br>! ;
print qq! Postcode: <input type="text", name="Pcode" , id="Pcode" size=30> <br>! ;
print qq! E-Mail: <input type="text", name="Email" , id="Email" size=15><br>! ;

 sub print_html_head_section {
 print "<head>\n";
 print "<script src='RegisterCustomerValidation.js'    type='text/javascript'></script>\n";
 print "</head>\n";
 }

print qq!<br /><input type="submit" value="Add"  style="width:50px"/>\n</form><br />!;

print end_html;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using paragraph so you would see the error on the next line EITHER do not use the para or put them in table to avoid formatting effort like this :

```
 <table> 
 <tr> 
  <Td>Firstname: <input type="text", name="Fname" , id="Fname" size=15>! ;
   </td>
  <td>
 <p id="f4"></p>
 </td>
 </tr>
```

and so on..

Comment: Thanks however this didn't change it

Comment: @TheHadimo try again,,I forgot <Td>

Comment: Still no luck, it just moves the input box to the bottom of the page. I'm also assuming you mean </td> instead of <td/>

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are using a

element, the p element makes your html to display what's inside to the next line. You should be using a span element if you want it next to your input.

I would advise you to change a bit your code and put each of your inputs in container  and add a span element inside so it is easier to manager what is where.
Plus you can create a better JS having a more flexible in avoiding using IDs, once your element change (using an event listener), you check it and if there is an error, you can got to its parent and scope the input inside:

```
event.currentTarget.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('span').innerHTML = 'your text';
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding the style attribute to the paragraph with Id **'f4'** as below:

```
style="position:relative:float:right;Margin-left:0px;"
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks however this just moved the comment to the far right of the page and not next to it

Comment: @TheHadimo: please check edit in my answer. I have added Margin-left:0px in style. can you check this please?